# Should I disable or drop indexes when doing a high volume insert on Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I'm doing a high-volume insert-into-select-from statement in Oracle, and I'm running out of undo space (ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace 'UNDOTBS1').

The general consensus seems to be to drop indexes on the target table and then recreate them when the insert completes.

Is just disabling the indexes/constraints on the table ok? How is it different from dropping the indexes/constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping the index should be faster for loading.  If you are not interested in the recoverability of the table you could also turn off logging during the insert on the table so it will not generate undo. The danger is that if the DBA needs to recover the database you will see corruption errors on the table.  Depending on the use of table/database that may be okay.  I would be rebuilding the index after the load to make sure everything indexed after the load of the data, so I do not believe that you would gain anything from turning it off.

Comment: Can you please clarify the difference between dropping and deactivating indexes/constraints?